# 3D Touch shortcuts won't work due to Unexpected Crash

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I am trying to add *3D Touch Shortcuts* to an application, I have managed to have the shortcuts appear when using *3DTouch* on the app icon from the *homescreen*; however when using the shortcut the application crashes on load and I am unsure why.

I have managed to get the application to load for the bookmarks shortcut but it does not initiate the `BookmarksViewController`, it just loads the `InitialViewController`.

The application is embedded within a `UITabBarController` and a `UINavigationController` for each Tab. Both View Controllers I am trying to load are in different tabs but the first view in the navigation controller stack.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong ?

**info.plist file**

[image]

**App Delegate**

```
enum ShortcutItemType: String {

case Bookmarks
case Favourites

init?(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) {
    guard let last = shortcutItem.type.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last else { return nil }
    self.init(rawValue: last)
}

var type: String {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier! + ".\(self.rawValue)"
}
}

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  
    if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
        handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem)
    }

    return true
}

private func handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) {

    if let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController, let shortcutItemType = ShortcutItemType(shortcutItem: shortcutItem) {
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil)

let favouritesVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FavouritesVC") as! FavouritesTableViewController
let bookmarksVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BookmarksVC") as! BookmarksNotesViewController

        switch shortcutItemType {
        case .Bookmarks:
            rootViewController.presentViewController(bookmarksVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break
        case .Favourites:
            rootViewController.presentViewController(favouritesVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            break
        }
    }
}


func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem)
}

}
```

**Storyboard ID**

These are the StoryboardID for the View Controllers.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I did exactly same thing with my project, after checking your code, the only difference is that I "return false" after handle the shortcut item in appDidFinishLaunchWithOption method to prevent it executing the performActionForShortcut item method. You may try it.

Comment: Can you provide stack trace for the crash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot the 's' in com.appName.Bookmark

[image]

Or you need to remove the 's' from Bookmarks here:

```
enum ShortcutItemType: String {

case Bookmarks
case Favourites
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead, try using a shortcut like this:

```
if shortcutItem.type == "com.appName.Bookmark"
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.appName.Bookmark" {

    }
}
```